# Obtaining lastest links from user through Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I want to obtain last links from specific user account.
I use this code:

```
<?php
require_once("sdk.php");

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '...';
$config['secret'] = '...';

$fb = new Facebook($config);

try {
    $links = $fb->api('/USER_ID/links', 'GET');
    print_r($links);
} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
?>
```

but all I get is:

```
Array ( [data] => Array ( ) )
```

despite the fact that user has some links added.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the user links using below code

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/links?fields=link&access_token=user_access_token
```

or as you use above make some changes

```
$links = $fb->api($User_Id .  '/links?fields=link&'. $access_token, 'GET')
```

Thanks

Comment: @user1010446 Your Welcome
feel nice to hear this
don't forget to accept answer

Answer (score 0):

try to replace 'USER_ID' with 'me'. The user is logged in facebook?

Comment: I want to obtain links from specific user, not from actual visitor